# ¿Cómo ordenar una lista de listas por fecha?

Tags: python-3.x

tengo una lista de listas la cual es de este formato: [[nombre, fecha, descripción], [nombre, fecha, descripción], [...]] y quisiera ordenar la lista según la fecha de las sublistas. Por ejemplo:

```
lista = [['Juan', '2019/03/03', 'hola como estas'], ['Diego', '2019/03/01', 'muy bien'], ['Pedro, '2019/03/02', 'adios']]
```

Busco poder ordenar de manera ascendente o descendente según la fecha. El output, si ordeno de forma ascendente deberia verse así:

```
lista_ascendente = [['Diego', '2019/03/01', 'muy bien'], ['Pedro, '2019/03/02', 'adios'], ['Juan', '2019/03/03', 'hola como estas']]
```

y descendente al revés:

```
lista_desc = [['Juan', '2019/03/03', 'hola como estas'], ['Pedro, '2019/03/02', 'adios'], ['Diego', '2019/03/01', 'muy bien']]
```

Comment: Y en que punto de tu código (o algoritmo de ordenación) te da problemas. ¿Puedes poner también ese código que intenta ordenar esas listas de listas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes usar `sort()`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list%20sort#list.sort

```
from datetime import datetime

lista = [
    ['Juan', '2019/03/03', 'hola como estas'],
    ['Diego', '2019/03/01', 'muy bien'],
    ['Pedro', '2019/03/02', 'adios']
]


def sortByDate(elem):
    return datetime.strptime(elem[1], '%Y/%m/%d')


lista.sort(key=sortByDate)
# [['Diego', '2019/03/01', 'muy bien'], ['Pedro', '2019/03/02', 'adios'], ['Juan', '2019/03/03', 'hola como estas']]

lista.sort(key=sortByDate, reverse=True)
# [['Juan', '2019/03/03', 'hola como estas'], ['Pedro', '2019/03/02', 'adios'], ['Diego', '2019/03/01', 'muy bien']]
```